# Hockey app download via api

Tags: hockeyapp

I'd like to ask, if it is possible to download a apk or ipa file using Hockey Api?

I can get the download_url per app_versions api. But that url gives me a html web page as response.

Is there any way to download the App with cUrl and co.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding *?format=apk* to the end of the download_url value retrieved via the HockeyApp API.

Note that I also had to update the first part of the URL from *https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/* to *https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/*.

Answer (score 0):

The info I got from HockeyApp:

This is possible by sending the following request:

```
GET /api/2/apps/APP_ID/app_versions?include_build_urls=true
```

You need to authorize with your API token and the API token needs to be owned by a developer of the app. The direct download URL is then included as the key "build_url".

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using shell command you can download hockey app

```
BUILD=$1
TOKEN="3a583f6d11164f0498f818a4e06c249e"
APP="ca47e3a4ce8a453cb40d8df4781beee5"
VERSION=$(curl \
-H "X-HockeyAppToken: $TOKEN" \
https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/$APP/app_versions \
| jq --arg BUILD "$BUILD" '.app_versions | .[] | select(.version==$BUILD) | .id')
curl -L -o $BUILD.apk https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/$APP/app_versions/$VERSION?format=apk
echo "!!!DONE!!!"
```